# Generate the output array A[] when the number of items greater than a[i] for indices greater than i is given

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given an `N`-length array `B`, find the permutation of `[1 .. N]`, `A`, such that `B[i]` is the number of elements in `A` that are greater than `A[i]` for all indices greater than `i`.

Example: `N = 4, B=[1 1 1 0]`

Output : `A=[3 2 1 4]`

Could anyone help me with an algorithm for this question?

Further explanation:  `B[i]` has the number of items greater than `A[i]` in array `A[]` after index `i`. i.e. for all indices greater than `i`. for eg : `B[2]=1` that means after the 3rd element in `A[]` there is one element that is greater than `A[2]`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you sure the question is complete/correct? "for all indices greater than I.."

Comment: sorry in case i have not made it clear. B[i] has the number of items greater than A[i] in array A[] after index i. i.e. for all indices greater than i. for eg : B[2]=1 that means after the 3rd element in A[] there is one element that is greater than A[2].

Comment: Are there any restrictions on `B`? (There possibly should be some, since not all arrays `B` are meaningful.)

Comment: @phimuemue It seems that the `i`th entry in `B` must be in the range from `0` through `N-1-i`. The gives `N!` different legal `B`, and they seem to be in one-to-one correspondence with the `N`-permutations.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work: Start with a temporary list `T := [ N, N-1, N-2, ..., 3, 2, 1 ]`. This list is indexed from `0` through `N-1` like a `List<int>` in C#.

Take `T[B[0]]`. That's you 0th member of the result array, so set `A[0] := T[B[0]]`. **Remove** this number from `T`. The list `T` now has one element less. It is now indexed `0` through `N-2`.

Then set `A[1] := T[B[1]]`, and remove that number from `T`. And so on, `A[i] := T[B[i]]`, where `T` at any time contains only the until then "unused" numbers.

In pseudo-code:

```
set T := [ N, N-1, N-2, ..., 3, 2, 1 ]
for (i from 0 through N-1)
    A[i] := T[B[i]]
    T.RemoveAtIndex(B[i])
```

The example from the question, `B=[1 1 1 0]`, goes like this:

- `T = [ 4, 3, 2, 1 ], A = [ ]`

Read and remove at index `1`:

- `T = [ 4, 2, 1 ], A = [ 3 ]`

Read and remove at index `1`:

- `T = [ 4, 1 ], A = [ 3, 2 ]`

Read and remove at index `1`:

- `T = [ 4 ], A = [ 3, 2, 1 ]`

Read and remove at index `0`:

- `T = [ ], A = [ 3, 2, 1, 4 ]`

---

Edit: I found out that this is called [Lehmer codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Numbering_permutations).

Answer (score 0):

One of the answers comes in my mind is the algorithm below:

```
For i = N to 1
   A[i] = N - B[i]
   For j = i+1 to N
      If A[j] <= A[i]
         A[j]--
```